# Spring boot with @RefreshScope @PostConstruct @PreDestroy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring boot application, we utilize `@RefreshScope` for dynamic reloading of beans after configuration changes. It works, but I have encountered an issue when combining the `@RefreshScope` on beans with methods annotated `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy`. It seems the `@PostConstruct` is not called after refresh.

When booting the app, the `@PostConstruct` method is called normally. When invoking refresh, the `@PreDestroy` method gets invoked normally as well, and I would expect `@PostConstruct` to be called on the new proxied bean instance, but it is not. There is important init/destroy-logic going on in these methods, so not having them called is a problem.

Anyone encountered the same problem, and is this a bug or a "feature"? Is there a way to make this work?

Best regards

Comment: How do you call the refresh? Using the url `/refresh` or programmatically!?

Comment: Hi, I use the /refresh and/or /bus/refresh endpoint. The latter, I suppose, simply runs the /refresh internally on receiving the message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I faced the same problem today and was able to solve it by calling a method on the `@RefreshScope`'d bean after the refresh. To accomplish this, I added an event handler for the `RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent` to the affected bean:

```
@EventListener
public void onRefreshScopeRefreshed(final RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event) {
    getClass();
}
```

As you can see it's a quite meaningless implementation, but nevertheless this method call on the bean triggers its initialization (the `@PostConstruct` method).

This behaviour conforms to the [documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/docs/1.0.x/spring-cloud.html#_refresh_scope):

> Refresh scope beans are lazy proxies that initialize when they are used (i.e. when a method is called),

But still I think that it's really a bug and that `@PostConstruct` should be called automatically after a refresh.

Comment: This works (but not sure why). Same as the OP stated, I also learnt from my test result that the `@PreDestroy` method will be called regardless of the existence of a `@EventListener` method. Also, the body of the `@EventListener` method can be empty and it will still trigger the `@PostConstruct` method. Besides, here is the new doc link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#refresh-scope